# SendInput to Ctrl+C text Doesn't Work When Launched from Hotkey

Tags: c++, winapi, sendinput

Currently using this code to Copy selected text in currently open Window in Windows 10. This code is working fine if I run it on its own by when my target program (Notepad) has focus. The selected text in notepad is copied into data variable OK.

```
wchar_t title[MAX_PATH];
HWND target_window = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowText(target_window, title, MAX_PATH);
std::wcout << "Target window is '" << title << "'" << std::endl;

// Send Control + C
int key_count = 4;

INPUT* input = new INPUT[key_count];
for (int i = 0; i < key_count; i++)
{
    input[i].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input[i].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
}

input[0].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
input[0].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
input[1].ki.wVk = 0x43; // Virtual key code for 'c'
input[1].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(0x43, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
input[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
input[2].ki.wVk = input[0].ki.wVk;
input[2].ki.wScan = input[0].ki.wScan;

input[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
input[3].ki.wVk = input[1].ki.wVk;
input[3].ki.wScan = input[1].ki.wScan;

if (!SendInput(key_count, (LPINPUT)input, sizeof(INPUT)))
{
    // TODO: error handling
}
else
{
    // not ideal but not sure of another way to wait for SendInput to complete
    Sleep(100); 
    if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
    {
        HGLOBAL hglb = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
        LPWSTR lpwstr = (LPWSTR)(GlobalLock(hglb));
        std::wstring data(lpwstr);
        GlobalUnlock(hglb);
        CloseClipboard();
        // do something with selected text in data
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: error handling
    }
}
```

However, if I launch the exact same code via Hotkey, it doesn't work:

```
if (RegisterHotKey(
    NULL,
    1,
    MOD_CONTROL | MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT,
    VK_OEM_2))  // back slash question mark key
{
    std::cout << "Hotkey 'Ctrl+Alt+/' registered, using MOD_NOREPEAT flag\n";
}

MSG msg = { 0 };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        std::cout << "WM_HOTKEY received\n";

        // Call function to COPY TEXT here

        if (RegisterHotKey(
            NULL,
            1,
            MOD_CONTROL | MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT,
            VK_OEM_2))  // back slash question mark key
        {
            std::cout << "Hotkey 'Ctrl+Alt+/' registered, using MOD_NOREPEAT flag\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in both cases, `GetWindowText()` is showing the title of the program I want to copy text from.

In addition, I wrote a simple test utility to check <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is being passed to Window, which it is.  It seems like <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is being passed, but the copy is not occurring.

Comment: The comment in your first code snippet suggests, that you want to process the data you just copied into the clipboard. If that is the case, then copying the data into the clipboard is inappropriate. The user may not want or even be aware of the fact, that some operation in your program destroys *their* clipboard data.

Comment: I am well aware of that; the clipboard will be backed up and restored in final program. If there is another way to grab text from any program without using clipboard then that would be preferable. However from what I've found other methods to grab text directly don't work consistently across all programs.

Comment: Why not just send `WM_GETTEXT` to the active input control of the foreground window? Look at [`GetGUIThreadInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506.aspx) to find that control.

Comment: As far as I know (but i am no expert on win32 programming) that will only work with standard windows controls or those that respond to that message, the requirement I am trying to meet is to grab the text selected by user in a variety of applications, some that are not based on standard windows control. I'm not sure if this will also tell me what text is selected by user or just text in the control, but i'll look into it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that <kbd>Alt</kbd> is still down because of the hotkey and you are actually sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>? `SendInput` inserts the input directly into the global input queue.

You could try setting a timer in response to the hotkey and call `GetAsyncKeyState` in the timer handler until all modifier keys are up before generating input.

A better alternative would be to use [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) instead of a hack like this.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState to check all modifier keys are up fixed the issue. I will also look into UI Automation framework but concerned it may not work with some 3rd party apps I need to integrate with.